# map over a hash-map, needs to return a hash-map

Tags: clojure

What the `map` function will be accepting will be a 'mapping' function and a hash-map. The mapping function will be accepting values of type MapEntry. That is because the collection (hash-map) coming in looks like this: `{k v k v k v}`, and a MapEntry is this: k v.

I cannot seem to get a `{k v k v k v}` to be returned. I can easily get `([k v] [k v] [k v])`.

Comment: [flatten](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/flatten)?

Comment: This is such a common use case (create a new map by applying some function to entries in an existing map) that I'm a little surprised there's nothing in clojure.core for it, even though it's trivial to implement yourself. There's `clojure.algo.generic.functor/fmap` from [algo.generic](https://github.com/clojure/algo.generic) but that only operates on values (and forces a third-party dependency).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought of this when just finished typing the question. All you need to do is `(into {} ([k v] [k v] [k v]))`. That will give `{k v k v k v}`.

Comment: Yep I believe this is the most idiomatic way, since `map` always returns a Seq